Product of $L^2[0,1]$ and $L^4[0,1]$ functions is in $L^3[0,1]$
We were assigned this example on our Functional analysis exam, I understand we have to use Hölder here, but I failed to provide p, q that satisfies this condition. Is there a different way to use Hölder here?
Given the following conditions:

$f \in L^2[0,1]$,
$g \in L^4[0,1]$,

prove that $f \cdot g \in L^3[0,1]$.

Taking $g=1$ would imply $ L^2 \subseteq L^3$

Are you sure this is the exact statement?

This is false. Take $f(x)=x^a,g(x)=x^b$.
$a>-\frac12$ and $b>-\frac14$ does not imply $a+b>-\frac13$.
